# Is there a way to maintain C++ array formatting when using VScode's default formatter upon saving?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When using the default VScode formatter for c++. I want to keep format on save but I don't want the array to be changed this drastically.

It changes an array from this

```
    const int level[] =
    {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0,
        2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    };
```

to this

```
    const int level[] = {
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        ...

    };
```

I want to keep format on save but I don't want the array to be changed this drastically.

Comment: Accoring to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide - if this is indeed the default formatter, the formatting is based on`clang-format` and I would be hopeful that clang-format has a setting for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are trying to keep using the default formatting engine for some reason, I can't find an option to change this behavior using the default, but this behavior is not present when setting the option  `C_Cpp:Formatting` (Extensions > C/C++ > Formatting > C_Cpp: Formatting) to `vcFormat`. If you just want format on save to not elongate your arrays Id use that engine option.